# How can I trigger Session Start (Global.asax) Event for a WebHandler Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Webhandler which generates an image on request in my asp.net Project. But if the user  directly access the resource, it won't trigger the session start Event in the Global.asax file. But in my project I need to trigger the session start event. How can I achieve this?

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session["Test"] = 1;

    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Session_Start` event is trigerred whenever some server side handler attempts to either read or write to the session. You might try decorating your handler with the [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) marker interface:

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using `System.Web.SessionState`. Right?

Comment: Let me ask you something more? Sometimes another Question? What if I want to use session in WebHandler but don't want to trigger the Session Start?

Comment: This is absolutely impossible. You cannot use any session without the Session_Start event being triggered. That's exactly what this event is designed for: being triggered before any server side handler attempts to access the session.

Comment: I want to load images only for users who visited my website. I want to prevent the image being shared on other websites. Not to secure my app but to avoid unwanted resource hogging

Comment: +1. @SubinJacob, you should carefully think about your requirements and ask separate question... It looks like "put images on CDN" could good option to avoid any resource usage on your server...

Comment: But I need an answer for this question. How can I disable webhandlers for requests outside from my website? @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Can I know the handler which  triggered the session start event

Answer (score 3):

You can always make a method of the `Session_Start` and call it

```
namespace WebFormsApplication1
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Global.StartSession();
        }
    }

    public static class Global 
    {
        public static void StartSession() {

            Session["Test"] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your Handler, simply call `Global.StartSession();`

Comment: Can I use session in WebHandler without triggering the session start event?