# How to clear static variable value and assing new

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-variables

I am calling an aspx website from my MVC project and passing two parameters

In Global.asax at Session_start I am assigning this parameters to two static variables

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            global.c = Request.QueryString["C"];
            global.u = Request.QueryString["U"];

        }
```

there is no logout in this aspx website.
First time the values are assigning correctly which is passing from the MVC
but for the next request it is showing the old values.

eg: https://www.xxxxxx.com/aa.aspx?C=2&U=2

This time it will show 2 and 2

next time if i call https://www.xxxxxx.com/aa.aspx?C=32&U=14

it will retain the 2 and 2.
Since there is no logout i can't use

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

since session will active for 20min default this value will be there..

How can i store these paremeter globally in aspx and use over all the pages.

Simeltaneously multiple user can access this aspx page with different parameters.

Comment: If this values are specific to an user, why don't you use cookies to store the parameter values and use them going forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the basic functionality first.

**STEP1:** Put debugger on session_start event. Break point will active when you will come first time with

https://www.xxxxxx.com/aa.aspx?C=2&U=2

**STEP2:** Now again hit the page with change in query string, you will notice that break point will not hit at time time.

**REASON:** Session start will hit once when session create and it will work for the same value throughout session.

**SOLUTION:** Go on client side to save some temp values as you already had done using query string on page load.

**PAGE1:** Assign cookie value

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (Request.Browser.Cookies)
        {
            //supports the cookies
         Response.Cookies["MyCookies"].Value = Request.QueryString["id"];
        }
    else
    {
        //not supports the cookies
        //redirect user on specific page
        //for this or show messages
    }
    }
```

**PAGE2:** Read Cookie value

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["MyCookies"] != null)
    {
        string userSettings = Request.Cookies["MyCookies"].Value;

    }

}
```

**OR**

You can follow [Trigger session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140461/how-can-i-trigger-session-start-global-asax-event-for-a-webhandler-request)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i created cookies to store the values at client but im little confused where should i use the cookie value assignment bcos i need to assign each time the default.aspx is loading..i put in page_load but it is not working.

Comment: Please check update i am able to add cookies on page load.

Comment: It you need variables to maintain for each session. Its better to put in cookies or also you can use Session["MyVariable"] = "My Value";

Comment: @Sunny what happening to me is..in this page load i wrote to store values to cookies. Then there is a button which lead to another page. There when i call this cookies or session variable im `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error..null value reference error..so it seems pageload event is not assigninvalues.

Comment: I had updated my answer to read and write cookies. It is working fine on my end.

Comment: @sunny thanks for the effort..it worked..some pblm with my aspx page i created new page and made it as default...and pag_load even fired now..i used page_init also..both works fine..thanks